# Autoscroll the horizontal scroll bar to show menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, superfish

I have used the superfish JQuery for horizontal menu. My Problem is rightmost menu item if user hover the childmenu item displays but user need to scroll horizontally to see that childmenu. Is there any mechanism to resolve this issue by autos-crolling or displaying child-menu in left side?
Please help.